# Is it possible to create a self contained ruby on rails package?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently looking into what language to build a web application on that will be sold to companies. To make things easier, I was hoping to package the webapp into a convenient installer that contains the entire stack which will run automatically.

Is there any way to create a self contained RoR package?

Comment: Maybe look into the thor gem.

Comment: You want Ruby and Ruby on Rails to be also included in the package?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that I could package everything including my RoR app so that we don't have to worry if they have ruby or rails installed on the server.

Comment: @JimPedid thor just parses command line arguments, it has nothing to do with creating a self-contained package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only project I'm aware of is called [pkgr](http://crohr.me/pkgr/), which bundles an entire rails app into a DEB package. So if you don't mind limiting your installs to Ubuntu/Debian, you could give it a try.

- [pkgr home page](http://crohr.me/pkgr/)
- [Github](https://github.com/crohr/pkgr)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a rake task to automatize everything for you. Migrations, bundling, enviroment setup. And it's pretty much plain Ruby, too.

In the end it would be just running a script file to do the job.